# Terminate ECS task using boto3 python api

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to terminate an ECS task after a specified timeout period using the boto3 python api? I currently call client.run_task() to place my task but I don't see any parameter in the documentation that can help me with a timeout.

For example, if my task runs for more than an hour, I would like to kill that task for good. Timeout would be 1 hour in this case.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: use a [waiter](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Waiter.TasksRunning) to poll for the amount of time you want and after failure call [stop](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.stop_task)